# MAUI Blazor App. Virtual keyboard covers textbox

Tags: blazor, keyboard, maui

I've started to create an app using Maui Blazor. When selecting a textbox (in my example the password field) the virtual keyboard pops up and covers the entry. Is there an automatic way to move the selected textbox back in to view when the virtual keyboard appears?

I have not tried anything because I don't know where to start and google hasn't helped.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the `Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` attached property to a value of the `WindowSoftInputModeAdjust` enumeration. It can resize the window when an input control has focus, to ensure the keyboard not covers the textbox. The code can be written in the App.xaml.cs file, you can refer to the following example:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using Application = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application;

namespace BlazorProject;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();

        Current.On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
    }
}
```

For more details, you can refer to [Soft keyboard input mode on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/platform-specifics/soft-keyboard-input-mode?view=net-maui-8.0)